# UserWarning: A node named [worker_name] is already using this process mailbox

Tags: celery, django-celery

I am using supervisor to start celery.I am continuously getting this warning

```
[2020-04-14 21:59:08,477: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/datasleek/trackervenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py:71: UserWarning: A node named worker1@%dev-tracker is already using this process mailbox!

Maybe you forgot to shutdown the other node or did not do so properly?
Or if you meant to start multiple nodes on the same host please make sure
you give each node a unique node name!

  warnings.warn(W_PIDBOX_IN_USE.format(node=self))
```

Though i am always killing celery processes using `sudo pkill -9 -f 'celery worker'` before calling `celery -A proj worker -l info`

This is supervisor conf for celery program.

```
[program:celery]
command = bash /home/datasleek/tracker/supervisor-config/celery_worker.sh
directory=/home/datasleek/tracker/
stdout_logfile=/home/datasleek/tracker/logs/celery_worker.log
stderr_logfile = /home/datasleek/tracker/logs/celery_worker_error.log
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
killasgroup=true
priority=998
```

celery_worker.sh

```
#!/bin/bash    
sudo pkill -9 -f 'celery worker'
cd /home/datasleek/tracker 
source ../trackervenv/bin/activate 
celery -A tracker worker -l info -n worker1@%%h
```

I have no idea why is this happening as i have also removed `autorestart=True` and `autostart=True` from `[program:celery]`.

Your help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks!

P.S: celery version is 4.2.1

Answer (score -1):

This is because of a user `worker1@%dev-tracker` already using this.

Change your supervisor conf file settings for command as below :

```
command = bash /home/datasleek/tracker/supervisor-config/celery_worker.sh --concurrency=10 -n worker1@%h
```